# Laravel: left join query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have such SQL query, which works fine:

```
SELECT A.program_id FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.program_id = B.program_id
WHERE
B.program_id IS NULL
```

But i want it to rewrite into LARAVEL style, like this:

```
\DB::table('A')
->join('B', 'A.program_id', '=', 'B.program_id')
->select('A.program_id')
->whereNull('B.program_id')
->get()->toArray();
```

But this code returns me 0 results.

Comment: Check what's your `$data['student_id']` contains ?

Comment: I have removed that part completely to avoid confusion. @Bibhudatta Sahoo solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **join** instead of **left join**

Try this

```
\DB::table('A')
->leftjoin('B', 'A.program_id', '=', 'B.program_id')
->select('A.program_id')
->whereNull('B.program_id')
->where('A.student_id', '=', 5)
->get()->toArray();
```

It will produce a query like
[image]

Comment: @LinasLg you are welcome as your problem solved then close your question by accepting my answer :)