# How to join other table and count the row in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to count how many require position there are for each jobseeker.
I have two tables: jobseeker and jobposition.

**jobseeker:**

```
+----+---------+-----------+----------------+
| id | fb_name | fullname  | desireposition |
+----+---------+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | John    | John Cena |              3 |
|  2 | Christ  | Christ    |              4 |
|  3 | Thomas  | Cfitcher  |              2 |
+----+---------+-----------+----------------+
```

and **jobposition:**

```
+----+--------+------------------+
| id | job_id | require_position |
+----+--------+------------------+
|  1 |     12 |                3 |
|  2 |     13 |                3 |
|  3 |     14 |                4 |
|  4 |     15 |                5 |
|  5 |     16 |                4 |
|  6 |     17 |                3 |
+----+--------+------------------+
```

My expected result is:

```
+----+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------------------+
| id | fb_name | fullname  | desireposition | total_requireposition |
+----+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | John    | John Cena |              3 |                     3 |
|  2 | Christ  | Christ    |              4 |                     2 |
|  3 | Thomas  | Cfitcher  |              2 |                     0 |
+----+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

I want to count how many require position there for each jobseeker.

Here is what I tried using `crossJoin`, but am unsure which join I actually need to be using.

```
$jobseekers = Jobseeker::crossJoin('jobpositions')
              >select('fullname','fb_name','desire_position', DB::raw('count(require_position) as total_requireposition'))
            ->groupBy('fullname')->paginate(10);
```

Can anyone help guide me? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `LEFT JOIN` to get zero counts.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone bro my query is not correct yet, even typo

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928276/laravel-left-join-query for how to write `LEFT JOIN` in Laravel.

Comment: left join need to be the same jobseeker id from jobseeker table and jobposition table, but in my case, i dun have jobseeker id in jobposition table @Barmar

Comment: @Sohel0415, bro I got it by the below answer. Thanks for answering me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular MySQL query you want is:

```
SELECT s.id, fullname, fb_name, desireposition, IFNULL(COUNT(require_position), 0) AS require_position
FROM jobseeker AS s
LEFT JOIN jobposition AS p ON s.desireposition = p.require_position
GROUP BY s.id
```

I don't use Laravel, but I think the translation would be:

```
$Jobseeker->select('fullname','fb_name','desire_position', DB::raw('IFNULL(COUNT(require_position), 0) as total_requireposition'))
        ->leftjoin('jobposition', 'desireposition', '=', 'require_position')
        ->groupBy('jobseeker.id')
        ->paginate(10)
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I got it, really appreciated